# Visualization of the fact that the integers defining lens spaces must be coprime

Tags: intuition, smooth-manifolds, visualization, low-dimensional-topology

This is related to this question I asked: [Visualization of Lens Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186778/visualization-of-lens-spaces) and is also related to this question by @Earthliŋ: [Why are the integers appearing in lens spaces coprime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421537/why-are-the-integers-appearing-in-lens-spaces-coprime)

I understand the formal explanation given as an answer to Earthliŋ, namely, that the requirement needed for the action defining the spaces to be free. However, I would like to somehow see geometrically/visually why, if we take two numbers which are not coprime, the resulting space turns out not to be a manifold.

Any suggestions for intuition will be greatly appreciated.